# How to show entry modified date in CP entry listings?

Tags: control-panel

With the Control Panel, is there a way to show an entries modified date within the entry listings rather than the creation date?

I believe it's possible with Zenbu but since that's all I would need it for purchasing that add-on would seem a little over the top.

Answer (score 1):

Zenbu is really awesome in my experience. But maybe if you just need to see the most recently edited entries this would help: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/recent-entries

Comment: It's not so much that I need to see the recently edited entries. My client wants to see the modified date in any entry listings in the CP. I guess I could hack the core but obviously that's not desirable.